# Test Android App over Remote Desktop

Tags: android

When I'm away from my computer, I like to use TeamViewer to access it and work on my Android apps. I save unsigned .apk files to my Google Drive so that I can test them while on the go, too. I download the .apk files to my Android device through the Drive app, but I'm having an issue.

When I go to install the App after downloading it from Google Drive, Android asks me if I'd like to install the App. When I click yes, it begins the install process but then exits with an "App Not Installed" error. There doesn't seem to be any other indication of what happened.

I've tried this with several of my .apk files, but they all give me the same issue. If it helps, these are apps I've previously downloaded by running the app with my android device plugged into my computer. I made sure to uninstall the app before trying to install it through the .apk file. I'm testing on a Google Nexus 7 32GB.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: And it works fine if you don't do it through TeamViewer...?

Comment: It's not really that TeamViewer is the issue, it's that when I try to install the app through its unsigned .apk I uploaded onto my Google Drive, it gives me the error I listed above. If I go to eclipse, select "run" and load it onto my device that way, everything runs smoothly.

Comment: There is probably some information in logcat with a detailed error. Did you look there?

Comment: You cannot install an unsigned APK. What comes out of the normal development process is an APK signed with the debug signing key, not an unsigned APK. There *is* a concept of an unsigned APK, but you have to go out of your way to create one normally, and it's usually just an interim step en route to signing it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Please make this an answer and I'll mark it as the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To me, it sounds like you are trying to install an APK that is signed with a different certificate than the one installed on the device.

Run logcat, and you will see a message with information on exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Have out tried [installing your unsigned APK through ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#move)? This should let you see any errors there are in installing that APK, such as security settings.

Answer (score 0):

According to a now-deleted(?) comment, you were trying to install an unsigned APK.

Alas, you cannot install an unsigned APK. Android -- emulators and devices alike -- only run signed APKs.

What comes out of the normal development process is an APK signed with the debug signing key, not an unsigned APK. There is a concept of an unsigned APK, but you have to go out of your way to create one normally, and it's usually just an interim step en route to signing it.